# where do I place the Django authentication backend file?

Tags: django, authentication

This documentation talks about writing the auth. backend but never said anything about where to place the file.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't really matter, since you have to add the path to `settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` anyways. But `<app>.backends` is generally safe.